# ContextMenu in Windows Phone project does not appear

Tags: windows-phone-8, contextmenu

I have problem with contextMenu in Windows Phone. It does not appear even in the project which I have downloaded from:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-contextmenu-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api
When I click the button from the project above nothing happens.

I was searching for the solution but I have not found. Any ideas?

Code sample which doesn't work:

```
           <Button Content="OpenContextMenu" Height="100" Width="270">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu  VerticalOffset="50.0" IsZoomEnabled="True"  x:Name="menu">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add"  Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Update"  Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete"  Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but i see that in comment : "You have to press and hold the button in order ti see the menu rather than just click it. That is the expected way in which Context Menu should appear in Windows Phone (press and hold). However if you want to show the menu on a single click of the button just set:
this.menu.IsOpen = true;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MatDev8 has suggested, you need to "press and hold" for the context menu to appear.